# Need Insights, Tips on development of a new Dot Net MVC 4.0 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, soa, single-page-application

I finally made up my mind to develop a Web Application for my Dad to help with his Astrology business, and after spending some good amount of time searching on Google and also taking my experience (Fresh Graduate) into account, I decided to go ahead with a basic MVC 4 Web Application.

Although after looking at the Service Oriented Architecture, I found that an API based back end could easily allow me to consume those services whilst developing native iOS and Android applications.

Also i came across Single Page Applications, and was wondering if it could serve as a Dashboard for the Astrologer (Dad), to view the requests for astrology that came about.

I wanted to develop this following the best practices and avoid using non standard practices since I want this to be a good learning experience as well.

Can somebody share their thoughts on the design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is correct. However, depending on your experience and need you might be over-engineering your application.

For instance, for the dashboard, I would simply use standard HTML and redirect the user to the different pages instead of using a SPA approach and replacing the view yourself.

Try not to use the latest techniques simply because they seem like everyone else is doing them. Use what is best for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start with the basic MVC then.